# Consul and Tomcat in the same docker container

Tags: docker, load-balancing

This is a two-part question.

First part:
What is the best approach to run Consul and a Tomcat in the same docker container?

I've built my own image, installing both Tomcat and Consul correctly, but I am not sure on how to start them. I tried putting both calls as CMD in the Dockerfile, but no success. I tried to put Consul as an ENTRYPOINT (Dockerfile) and Tomcat to be called in the "docker run" command. It could be vice versa but I have a feeling that it is no good way either.

The docker will run in one AWS instance. Each docker container would run Consul as a server, to register themselves in another AWS instance. Consul and Consul-template will be integrated into proper load balance. This way, my HAproxy instance will be able to correctly forward the requests as I plug or unplug containers.

Second part:
In individual tests I did, the docker container was able to reach my main Consul server(leader) but it failed to register itself as an "alive" node.

Reading the logs at Consul server, I think is a matter of which ports I am exposing and publishing. In AWS, I already allowed communication in all ports in TCP and UDP between the instances in this particular Security Group.

Do you know which ports I should be exposing and publishing to allow proper communication between a standalone consul(aws instance) and consul servers (running inside docker containers inside a aws container)? What is command to run the docker container: docker run -p 8300:8300 .........

Thank you.

Comment: My AWS instance has the IP 172.30.0.165. When docker is running it has a second IP address. 172.17.0.2. Also, my docker image was built exposing the following ports: 8080 53/udp 8300 8301 8301/udp 8302 8302/udp 8400 8500 8600 8600/udp. I ran the container publishing the following ports as "docker run -p 8300:8300 -p 8301:8301 -p 8301:8301/udp -p 8302:8302 -p 8302:8302/udp -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 53:53/udp -p 8600:8600/udp container_label".


From another AWS instance, I cannot reach, using telnet for example, the ports 8301, 8302. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not to answer but the Docker best practice is  Caas: Container as a Service. Which actually means that you are not suppose to run two services in a single container. [Just yesterday a video has been released on blog.docker.com: Docker Containers-as-a-Service Walkthrough](https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/video-containers-as-a-service-caas/). I suggest you to use [Docker Compose ](http://docs.docker.com/compose/) to start both of these services at the same time and manage multi-containers applications.

Comment: I completely understand the Caas idea but I find it a bit paradoxical. I can't see the advantage of having a service discovery system running without having the service itself, there, available. I mean, what is the purpose of having a container running a consul server but doing "nothing"?

Comment: It does not do nothing, it is coupled (thanks to compose) with the service it advertises.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Any ideas why the consul leader is not able to reach the consul inside the docker container?

Comment: Can you ping each other?

Comment: Ping usually are not available in AWS instances. But I can use telnet to reach other between AWS instances but, on the other hand, I cannot reach from outside, the docker container inside the AWS instance.

Comment: Still struggling to make it work...

Comment: Too few details for us to debug. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ENTRYPOINT to kick off a script on docker run.

Something like

```
ENTRYPOINT myamazingbashscript.sh
```

Syntax might be off but u get the idea

The script should start both services and finally should tail -f the tomcat logs (or any logs).

tail -f will prevent container exit since the tail -f command never exits and it will also help u to see what tomcat is doing

Do ... docker logs -f to watch the logs after a docker run

Note because the container doesn't exit u can exec into it with ... docker exec -it containerName bash

This lets you have a sniff around inside the container

Not generally the best approach to have two services in one container because it destroys the separation of concerns and reusability but u may have valid reasons

To build use docker build then run with docker run as u stated it.

If u decided to go for a 2 container solution then u will need to expose ports between containers to allow them to talk to each other. You could share files between containers using volumes_from

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot! God bless you too.