# How to make Docker container accessible to other network machines through IP?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I need to create some docker containers that must be accessed by other computers at the same network.

Problem is that when I create the container, Docker gets IP addresses valid only within the host machine.

I already took a look at Docker documentation (Networking) but nothing has worked.

If I run `ifconfig` on my machine my IP address is `172.21.46.149`. When I go inside the container (Ubuntu) and run `ifconfig` the IP address is `172.17.0.2`. I need Docker to get, for example, `172.21.46.150`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Would it be OK if your container would directly bind host port to communicate?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a bridge on your host and assign that bridge to the container. This may help you: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/

Answer (score 2):

Multi-host access involves an **overlay network** with **service discovery**.
See [docker/networking](https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/blob/master/06-networking.md):

> An overlay network requires a **key-value store**. The store maintains information about the network state which includes discovery, networks, endpoints, IP Addresses, and more.
>   The Docker Engine currently supports Consul, etcd, ZooKeeper (Distributed store), and BoltDB (Local store) key-value store stores.
>   This example uses Consul.

[image: https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/raw/master/images/tut6-step1.png]

If if your your nodes (the other computers across the same network) runs their docker daemon with a reference to that key-value store, they will be able to communicate with containers from other nodes.

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --cluster-store=consul://<NODE-0-PRIVATE-IP>:8500/network --cluster-advertise=eth0:2375"
```

You just need to create an overlay network:

```
 docker network create -d overlay --subnet=10.10.10.0/24 RED
```

(it will be available in all computers because of the key-value store)

And run your containers on that network:

```
docker run -itd --name container1 --net RED busybox
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers can easily be accessed by other network node when a container:port is published through a host:port.

This is done using the `-p` docker-run option. Here is the sum-up of the man-page (`$man docker-run` gives more details and example that I won't copy/paste):

```
   -p, --publish=[]
      Publish a container's port, or range of ports, to the host.
```

See the [doc online](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port-p-expose). This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22150099/5321002) could be interesting to read too.

Basically:

`docker run -it --rm -p 8085:8080 my_netcat nc -l -p 8080`

Would allow LAN nodes to connect to the docker-host-ip:8085 and discuss with the netcat command.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that when I grow my environment things will get a bit messy I think as long as I will have many many containers...

Comment: Well... You may want to edit your question to make it clearer then. Do you actually need all the containers on the same LAN as the host LAN? I understand the many-container-reason but I doubt the host will run more than 65k containers (creating a lack of socket to bind). Remember that a Docker best practice is the ["Caas"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610995/consul-and-tomcat-in-the-same-docker-container#comment58922618_35610995) and according to the CaaS the container (supposed to run a single service) should need one port only, two or three in exceptional multi-ports-service cases.