# Docker overlay networking centos7

Tags: networking, docker

After pulling out all my hair. Trying to get docker overlay network on a 3 node CentOS7 swarm cluster, I need some help please.

1 - Upgraded kernel on all nodes 4.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
2 - Docker Version : Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd (same on all nodes)
Docker info:

```
Filters: health, port, dependency, affinity, constraint<br>
Nodes: 3<br>
 docker1: 192.168.1.231:2375<br>
  └ Status: Healthy<br>
  └ Containers: 5<br>
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1<br>
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 2.033 GiB<br>
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=4.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper<br>
  └ Error: (none)<br>
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-04-04T03:16:04Z<br>
 docker2: 192.168.1.35:2375<br>
  └ Status: Healthy<br>
  └ Containers: 3<br>
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1<br>
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 2.033 GiB<br>
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=4.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper<br>
  └ Error: (none)<br>
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-04-04T03:16:12Z<br>
 docker3: 192.168.1.36:2375<br>
  └ Status: Healthy<br>
  └ Containers: 2<br>
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1<br>
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 2.033 GiB<br>
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=4.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64, operatingsystem=CentOS Linux 7 (Core), storagedriver=devicemapper<br>
  └ Error: (none)<br>
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-04-04T03:16:20Z<br>
Plugins:<br>
 Volume:<br>
 Network:<br>
Kernel Version: 4.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64<br>
Operating System: linux<br>
Architecture: amd64<br>
CPUs: 3<br>
Total Memory: 6.099 GiB<br>
Name: 21131682ca99<br>
```

Creating the overlay network works fine

docker network create -d overlay --subnet=10.10.10.0/24 RED

Then create two test containers, one on each docker node:

```
docker1
 docker run -itd --name container1 --net RED busybox<br>
docker2
 docker run -itd --name container2 --net RED busybox<br>
```

Check network:

```
docker -H :4000 network inspect RED
[
    {
        "Name": "RED",
        "Id": <br>"f64fcb769bba4a4b0d709599e9670657ee2cba3c98ca031909bc3967b6085867",
        "Scope": "global",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.10.10.0/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {
            "1371c2fec957fe2ecd9d9d9dcf21492e63ef497c662a4b7eee7e8170738875b2": {
                "Name": "container1",
                "EndpointID": "e1e5d0d0c794da9f7a9054e0012bb184b10501c4cdd537193608a38bafa1ee00",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:0a:0a:02",
                "IPv4Address": "10.10.10.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
  "489c7963b7484041a7ef7647b7383a69dfdde8eb416e0a26aa41a023e154ab5f": {
                "Name": "container2",
                "EndpointID": "3d3afb54922d4b904056fc637e7f76cbfe632230a730860ecde88e12ec9f16f2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:0a:0a:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.10.10.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
```

I'm unable to ping from one container to another across the different hosts.
It does of course work when both containers are on the same host.
Any help/suggestions please.

Comment: You should wear a wig. Maybe you can make it out of the hair you pulled out.

Comment: Can you give more details about your setup..how have you configured the clusters and which store are you using?

Comment: Have you tried, instead of pinging, making a connection to a port on the other container which you know should be accessible? It's possible that ping just doesn't work across an overlay network but regular IP connections (e.g. http over tcp) do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that a multi-machine overlay network supposes you need a key-value store, as I showed in "[How to make Docker container accessible to other network machines through IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35716757/6309)" and in [this tutorial](https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/blob/master/06-networking.md).

[image: kv store]

That means your docker daemon must be started with a reference to that key-value store.

See also "[Swarm and container networks](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/networking/)":

> **Multi-host networks require a key-value store**.
>   The key-value store holds information about the network state which includes discovery, networks, endpoints, IP addresses, and more.
>
> You configure the Docker Engine daemon to use this store.
>   Two required parameters, `--cluster-store` and `--cluster-advertise`, refer to your key-value store server.

Comment: Hi. Yes I have the /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf configuration set to the consul for the cluster

`[Service]ExecStart=ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://192.168.1.35:2375  --cluster-store=consul://192.168.1.231:8500 --cluster-advertise=192.168.1.35:2375`

Comment: If you don't have the kv store running and accessible from the docker daemon, then you would get an error when you try to create the overlay network - you certainly wouldn't have the overlay network up and running, but have communication problems across it.